# Fourier Sine transform of $\arctan(x/a)$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, transformation, trigonometric-integrals

How can I find the Fourier sine transform of $arctan(x/a)  ;a>0$? I am solving it as,
$$F_{s}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\sin(wx)dx$$
$$F_{s}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left[ \left|\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\frac{\cos(wx)}{w}\right|^{\infty}_{0}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}\frac{\cos(ws)}{w}dx\right]$$

Since $\cos(\infty)$ is undefined, I am not able to evaluate the definite integral in the term inside the bracket.

How can I solve it? Should I go for different approach to find Fourier sine transform of $\arctan(x/a)$?
Please clarify my doubts!
Thank you!

Comment: This should work fine. That last integral with cosine is solvable by Feynman trick.

Comment: Yes, the second term is solvable. But what about the first term inside bracket?

Comment: Then perhaps it might be best to compute the Fourier transform of that instead, use the antiderivative property then take the imaginary part.

Comment: Can you elaborate the antiderivative technique please?